# How can we write karate code inside karate loop?

Tags: api, automation, karate

This is one of the simple loop mentioned in karate ducumentation (https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops):

```
* def fun = function(i){ return i * 2 }
* def foo = karate.repeat(5, fun)
```

Suppose I want to execute and validate the api based input parameter which I created using loop:

```
Scenario: Test scenario
Given url baseUrl
And path "api/test"
And params {"testData" : #(getFromLoop)} 
When method get
Then status 200
And match response == ExpectedResponse
```

Now "getFromLoop" is the data, which I need to get with the help of loop and pass in api each time with multiple set of data generated by loop.

Comment: can you please spend more time reading the docs and examples, it will save you a lot of time

Comment: @PeterThomas
 my question is very simple "How can we write karate code inside karate loop?"

The question, which you have linked does not answer my quesion. 
Request you read my question again.

Comment: if the question is `How can we write karate code inside karate loop` - the answer is no - you can't, so maybe you need to look for another framework. if the question is how to make an API call in a loop, that is exactly what the linked question answers (make sure you read the links also)